# Ruby on Rails invalid date error when parsing datetime string to convert to a different format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-2, strptime

In my Rails App (Rails 2.3.14 and  Ruby 1.8.7) I am trying to convert a datetime string into a different format to perform a search on my MySQL database but I am getting an  `invalid date` error and I can't seem to figure out why, I've read a good few similar questions but I still can't seem to resolve the issue.

```
# check if filter contains a time stamp
if params[:sSearch].include?('/') and params[:sSearch].include?(':')
  datetime = DateTime.strptime(params[:sSearch], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
  params[:sSearch] = datetime
end
```

Example scenario

```
04/11/13 16:14
```

should convert to

```
2013-11-04 16:14
```

I thought it might have been to do with the fact that the seconds aren't included in the front-end representation of the string as the precise `datetime` in the database table is `2013-11-04 16:14:52` so I included the seconds now but still getting the same error and I don't think that should matter since I am using the `LIKE` operand with wildcards on either side of the search term, so even without the seconds it should work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use slashes in the format and replace `%Y` (four digit year) with `%y` (abbreviated two digit year) to get the desired result. Besides, the order of the date fields is reversed. The correct format would be:

```
"%d/%m/%y %H:%M"
```

I think you confused the purpose of `strptime` and `strftime`. Whereas the `p` in `strptime` stands for "parse" (make `DateTime` from `String`), the `f` in `strftime` stands for "format" (the other direction).

```
require 'date'

DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
# ArgumentError: invalid date

DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
#=> #<DateTime: 0013-11-04T16:14:00+00:00 ((1722836j,58440s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# Wrong! You do not want the year 0013, but 2013

DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")
#=> #<DateTime: 2004-11-13T16:14:00+00:00 ((2453323j,58440s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
# Correct
```

you can later convert it to the desired format with `DateTime#strftime` like this:

```
# parse the user input to a DateTime object
datetime = DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")

# reformat it
params[:sSearch] = datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```

Comment: You're the smartest one on this site.

Comment: I'm humbled, but I doubt that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your template, try: `DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%d/%m/%y %H:%M")`

Comment: I thought the parsing was built into the `strptime` function? - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#M000214. I'd rather not use a gem just for this tiny bit of functionality.

Comment: "I'd rather not use a gem just for this tiny bit of functionality."? You're using Rails; It's made up of a whole bunch of gems. A well written gem doesn't incur any sort of cost over using something from the standard library, it's just not part of the Ruby distribution.

Comment: I think he meant that he would rather not use a gem if he didn't need to, chronic is a nice gem but might be overkill if you don't need its features.

Answer (score 1):

`strptime` converts the given string into a datetime object using the format given.

```
DateTime.strptime("04/11/13 16:14", "%m/%d/%y %H:%M").strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
```